# ExtJS 4.2.1 Navigation between different Views - best practice

Tags: javascript, extjs, navigation, extjs4.2

Im going to write an ExtJS Application in which i need to Navigate between several Views..
Im questioning myself right now what the best practice is for this issue..

One solution with which im not really 100% happy is to change my url when i press on a link/button in combination with a TaskRunner which is always checking if the url has been changed.

I do also want a history so when i do press the "back" button in my browser i can jump back to the former view which would work with the solution above.
I dont know if the solution above is taking much resources?

Is there a better way? Do you think that my solution is ok? Please tell me!
If you need any more information dont hesitate to ask ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use `Ext.ajax` to load partial views (e.g. the whole content of that tab) or pure `Ext JS` to create them and use [this technique](http://interactivevolcano.com/browser-back-button-javascript) to honour the browser history.

Once a tab is loaded once you just switch to hiding/showing each associated tab panel as the tab is clicked.

You might also consider [Ext's card layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card).

[And here's](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs%3atab1%3asubtab1) a fully integrated ext js solution of what you want.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the Ext.History class. Very useful and easy to implement :) Thanks.